# Using "property" in HTML meta data with kotlin DSL

Tags: html, kotlin, ktor, kotlin-dsl, kotlin-html-builder

Hey how can i use html content like:

`<meta property="og:locale" content="en"/>`

with the Kotlin HTML Type Safe builder? I cannot find something like the property variable in the meta function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```kotlin
meta(content = "en") {
    attributes["property"] = "og:locale"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A typesafe extension to the answer of @Михаил Нафталь, in case you need to use a lot of those tags, is this:

```
fun HEAD.metaProperty(propertyName: String, content: String) = meta(content = content) {
    attributes["property"] = propertyName
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
val htmlCode = buildString {
    appendHTML().html {
        head {
            metaProperty("og:locale", "en")
        }
        body {
            h1 { +"Hello" }
        }
    }
}
println(htmlCode)
```